# how to install react-pannellum library to react/ionic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ionic-framework, pannellum

I need to implement 3d panorama view in my react ionic app but I'm getting an error when I try install using either of the followings:

`npm install --save react-pannellum`

`npm install --save pannellum`

> ```
> > npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use
> > `--location=global` instead.
> > 
> > npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> > 
> > npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> > 
> > npm ERR! While resolving: test-pannelum@0.1.0
> > 
> > npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
> > 
> > npm ERR! node_modules/react
> > 
> > npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
> > 
> > 
> > npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> > 
> > npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-pannellum@0.2.13
> > 
> > npm ERR! node_modules/react-pannellum
> > 
> > npm ERR!   react-pannellum@"*" from the root project
> > 
> > 
> > npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> > 
> > npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> > 
> > npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
> > resolution.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install --save react-pannellum --force
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). You might be able to delete the post yourself as well.